# Pylance doesn't show annotation descriptor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm using visual code 1.61.2 with pylance v2021.10.3 , python 3.9.6 on my mac.

When I create a function with an annotation descriptor, pylance will not show de annotation (when hovering over the function call) but shows 'Any'.

The annotation get also an error 'annotation is not defined (reportUndefinedVariable)'
when I create pyrightconfig.json and put "reportUndefinedVariable": false, then this error goes away

}

[image]

Comment: But, looks like it should be like this.